# While Tomcat localhost is running, other War file is not running due to ports already in use

Tags: java, tomcat, port

I have my Tomcat up and running and I am able to run example files. But when I am try to run my war file which resides in websapps folder, Tomcat says 8080, 8009, 8005 are already in use and I am receiving 404 error when I run my code. I am wondering why I am receiving port conflicts when I run my war file but not when I am running tomcat example file.

Comment: How you run your war file? and how you run the tomcat examples? Are they in the same server? Have you stopped the examples before running the server with your war file?

Comment: @SimoneGianni :  My war file is in my webapps folder. It's a war file named project-dev. When I go http://localhost:8080/project-dev I am receiving 404 error (and in log file I see many SEVER errors telling that my ports are already in use). However when I go to http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample it works.

Comment: Unless you are running a (very) custom configuration, once you start your tomcat, it will deploy the wars in the webapps folder, but open the ports only once and only at the beginning, so should not give port errors when you go to your application, unless you're running two tomcats, one running the examples and the other trying to get the busy 8080 port, and what you see is the log of the second tomcat.

Comment: @SimoneGianni Thanks Simone. I don't have any special configuration and I don't think I have two instances of tomcat running. How can I check to see if I have two instances running?

btw this is the error that I am receiving for different ports:SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use